# MYSQL Alias: Unable to give a name to new table

Tags: mysql, alias

[image]

I have 3 tables given and I want to join all them and give this new table a name 'newtab'.
I did this:

```
(select s1.Name as name, s1.ID as id, f1.Friend_ID as id, p1.Salary as sal
from Students as s1, Friends as f1, Packages as p1
where s1.ID=f1.ID AND s1.ID=p1.ID
) as newtab
```

now the problem is its showing error using 'as newtab'.
How can I give this new table a name in MYSQL?

Comment: Is that your full query code?

Comment: If you want to create new table you must use `CREATE TABLE newtab SELECT ...`

Comment: no but this is all you need to answer my question.

Comment: akina, I want to select first column of this new table. how should i do it?

Comment: Please clarify your goal - do you need a query which retrieves combined data or create one more static table which stores such data.

Answer (score 1):

The code segment on it's own is syntactically incorrect you need a main query

eg

```
SELECT * FROM
(select s1.Name as name, s1.ID as id, f1.Friend_ID as id, p1.Salary as sal
from Students as s1, Friends as f1, Packages as p1
where s1.ID=f1.ID AND s1.ID=p1.ID
) as newtab
```

you should also replace comma joins with explicit joins

'no but this is all you need to answer my question' - the answer to the question then is that as standalone code this is syntactically incorrect - but you know that already.

Comment: thank u. got it. but it worked  without using 'as' in MYSQL.

Comment: as is optional for alias in any sql dialect.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to give a query an alias which is not possible, it's only plausible in [...from table_name as alias_name...]

```
select s1.Name as name, s1.ID as id, f1.Friend_ID as id, p1.Salary as sal
```

No need to give alias to the column name that have the same alias name.Alias are used when you want a different name
Like:

```
select s1.Name as Student_Name, s1.ID as Student_ID, f1.Friend_ID, p1.Salary as sal
```

Please Note: if I don't specify alias then from the column s1.Name, "Name" will be displayed as column name by default.

```
select s1.Name as name, s1.ID as id, f1.Friend_ID as id, p1.Salary as sal
from Students as s1, Friends as f1, Packages as p1
where s1.ID=f1.ID AND s1.ID=p1.ID;
```

removing the "as newtab", the query should work fine.